# Proving divisibility of a large number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I need to prove that $2005\mid555\ldots 555$ there is the total of 800 digits.
I've factorised $2005=5\times401$ and trivial reduced the problem to $401\mid 111 \ldots 111$.
On every 200 digits there is a repeating pattern of remainders and because $200\mid 800$ that would prove it, but is there an easier way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. To show that $401|111\ldots 111$ you can write:

$$111\ldots 111 = \frac{1}{9}(10^{800}-1)$$

And now it suffices to show that $401|10^{800}-1=(10^{400}-1)\cdot(10^{400}+1)$.

But $401|10^{400}-1$ because $401$ is prime and Fermat's Little Theorem does its magic here.

Comment: You don't even have to factor $10^{800}-1$ to show that. Little Fermat is enough.